# Change stacked bar plot legend in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have the following data in a csv file:

```
Date    City    TruckA  TruckB  TruckC  TruckD
Date1   City1   1   0   0   0
Date1   City2   0   0   1   0
Date1   City3   1   0   0   0
Date1   City4   0   0   1   0
Date2   City1   1   0   0   0
Date2   City2   0   1   0   0
Date2   City3   0   0   0   1
Date2   City4   1   0   0   0
Date2   City5   0   1   0   0
Date3   City1   1   0   0   0
Date3   City2   0   0   1   0
Date3   City3   1   0   0   0
Date3   City4   0   0   1   0
```

I can successfully plot the data with this code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

print(df)

df = df.set_index(["Date","City"])

df.unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

I get the following result:
[image]

As you can see, the color legend is such as each pair (City,Truck) has a color. I would like the legend to only depend on the Truck, and ideally have  labels on the bar chart for each City.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Following @Scott's great answer you can get the stacked columns as desired.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cycle = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']
df_out = df.unstack()
d = dict(zip(df.columns.get_level_values(0),cycle))
c = df_out.columns.get_level_values(0).map(d)
g=df_out.plot.bar(stacked=True, color=c, figsize=(10,8), edgecolor='k')
```

To add the labels thou you need to find the right position and label iteratively.
Here is one way to do it:

### EDIT: One loop only

```
h=0
x=0
unique_dates=df1.index.get_level_values(0).unique() # get the bars
city=df_out.iloc[x][df_out.iloc[x]!=0].dropna().index.get_level_values(1) #get the cities
for y,val in enumerate(df1.index.get_level_values(0)): #loop through the dates
    if val==unique_dates[x]: #check the x position
        g.text(x-0.05,1+h-0.5,"%s" % city[h]) 
        h+=1
    else:                                             # move to next x coord, update city labels and add text for the next x coordinate (h=0)
        x+=1
        city=df_out.iloc[x][df_out.iloc[x]!=0].dropna().index.get_level_values(1) #get cities
        g.text(x-0.05,1-0.5,"%s" % city[0])
        h=1      # set h to 1 as we already printed for h=0
```

Original solution

```
for x ,date in enumerate(df_out.index):
    h=0
    city=df_out.iloc[x][df_out.iloc[x]!=0].dropna().index.get_level_values(1) #get cities
    for y,val in enumerate(df.index.get_level_values(0)):
        if val==date:
            g.text(x,1+h-0.5,"%s" % city[h])
            h+=1
        else:
            continue
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working for the data I provided. I have a much larger dataset, with 260 rows x 9 columns. Surprisingly, for 120 rows x 9 columns, it was done in a few seconds bur for the full data set it's taken 50 minutes. Any idea which could improve the performance ?

Comment: Great answer... +1. However, could there be another way without two for loops?

Comment: @ScottBoston @to25. You could get the x position using `unique()`. Something like:         `unique_dates=df1.index.get_level_values(0).unique()`. I am quite busy this morning but I'm positive you can easily remove the first for loop.

Comment: @to25 see the updated answer, I assume it will be faster.

Comment: Thanks for the update.I made a few changes to the text size and position and it's now perfect !
 
It looks like what's slowing it down is Scott's part to set apart the cities. If there's any solution to this it would be great, if not, no worries !

Answer (score 2):

## Edit

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cycle = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']
df_out = df.unstack()
d = dict(zip(df.columns.get_level_values(0),cycle))
c = df_out.columns.get_level_values(0).map(d)
df_out.plot.bar(stacked=True, color=c, figsize=(10,8))
```

Output:

[image]

Added edgecolor to set apart the cities:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cycle = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']
df_out = df.unstack()
d = dict(zip(df.columns.get_level_values(0),cycle))
c = df_out.columns.get_level_values(0).map(d)
df_out.plot.bar(stacked=True, color=c, figsize=(10,8), edgecolor='k')
```

[image]

---

IIUC, I think you are looking for something like this:

```
df = df.set_index(["Date","City"])
df.sum(level=0).plot.bar(stacked=True, figsize=(10,8))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: First, thank you very much for the answer. 

That's not exactly what I am looking for. The figure I am looking for is like the one I posted, except that there should be just 4 different colors, one for each truck type. And each "box" represents a city.  Thanks!

Comment: @to25 I think this is what you are looking for, however, I think needs a different border color to set apart the different cities.

Comment: Great that's what I was looking for! Is there any possibility to add a label with the city name on each box ?